# React - reorder JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm making a simple app for returning movie information from TMDb. I can retrieve the data and order it by popularity and average vote.

However, I'm struggling with returning it to the original order retrieved from TMDb.

This is the function I use to sort the data:

```
sortBy = (param) => {
        let movies = [];
        if(param.target.value === 'popularity'){
          this.setState({sort:'popularity'})
          movies = this.state.movies.sort((a,b) => {
            return parseFloat(b.popularity) - parseFloat(a.popularity)
          });
        } else if (param.target.value === 'vote_average'){
          this.setState({sort:'vote_average'})
          movies = this.state.movies.sort((a,b) => {
            return parseFloat(b.vote_average) - parseFloat(a.vote_average)
          });
        }
        this.setState({
          movies: movies
        });
}
```

Now, if I have 'param.target.value' set to 'match' I would like to restore the original order of the data. This was stored in state.movies, but this gets changed at the end of the function. Is the best option just to keep some original order state?

Comment: Add the data you work with...

Comment: Why don't you just order it on load (by date for instance) and use that sort function to go back to the original state?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious options are to keep a copy in the original order like you mentioned, or add some field (e.g. "id") which records the original order.

If you know how the data is initially ordered by TMDb, you may be able to restore that order without having to add an extra field. On the other hand, if the initial order is arbitrary consider sorting the data from the start like [@Rienk suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45928868/react-reorder-json-data#comment78816487_45928868).

Answer (score 0):

Its better to keep a copy in such cases

const movies = await get_from_IMDB();

const movies_copy = [...movies];
this.setState({movies,movies_copy});

Now on sorting, perform your operations as you are doing.
And finally when you have to revert to initial list, just perform

this.setState({movies: movies_copy})

Make sure to use the spread operator (...) to break the referencing in array.